# Fetch selected data value from kendoui drop down list

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get the data parameter of the selected item from a KendoDropDownList which is being used as an custom filter editor for my grid.

I have:

```
function gradeSelector(element)
{
  element.kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: {
      transport: {
        read: {
          type: "POST",
          url: ROOT+'record/fetchGrade',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            mode: 'obj'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    optionLabel: "Select grade",
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "id",
    template: '#="<span class=\'filterTrigger\' data-value=\'"+id+"\'>"+text+"</span>" #',
    select: function(e) 
    {// Dirty, is there a better way?
      html = e.item[0].outerHTML;
      html = html.substring(html.indexOf('data-value="')+12);      
      gradeId = html.substring(0, html.indexOf('"'));

      clearSingleFilter('grade');
      activeFilter.push({
        field: 'grade',
        operator: 'eq',
        value: gradeId
      })
      $('.k-animation-container').hide();
      filtersState = 1 ;
      $('#customerGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter(activeFilter);
    }
  });
}
```

The way I get gradeId looks very messy. What is the proper way to retrieve this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `close` event instead of `select` and then you can simply do:

```
close         : function (e) {
    // Easily get gradeId
    var gradeId = this.select();

    clearSingleFilter('grade');
    activeFilter.push({
        field   : 'grade',
        operator: 'eq',
        value   : gradeId
    })
    $('.k-animation-container').hide();
    filtersState = 1;
    $('#customerGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter(activeFilter);
}
```

The "problem" with `select` is that it is triggered before the element is triggered so you cannot (easily) get the value but `close` is triggered after the values is actually selected.

**EDIT:** Previous implementation will fail if the list of `id` is not sorted and consecutive. As a general solution you should use:

```
close         : function (e) {
    // Get index in the list
    var idx = this.select();
    // Get the item corresponding to that index
    var item = this.dataItem(idx);
    // Now, we can get the id from the item
    var gradeId = item.id;
    console.log("gradeId", gradeId);

    clearSingleFilter('grade');
    activeFilter.push({
        field   : 'grade',
        operator: 'eq',
        value   : gradeId
    })
    $('.k-animation-container').hide();
    filtersState = 1;
    $('#customerGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter(activeFilter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have noticed that now I need to offset the value because the selection is always one higher than the one you pick. E.g. In your answer I now have to do gradeId+1 for it to get the intended item, any ideas why?

Comment: @imperium2335 actually the problem is much worse that adding 1. The question is that my solution is returning the index in the list but if the list is not sorted and consecutive it does not work :-( Check **EDIT** for fixed solution.